# Host Resolution from a Windows 7 Workstation not on a Domain

Tags: windows-7, domain, hostname

My Windows 7 Workstation is not on a domain, but I frequently use resources on 'team.domain'. I have a static IP and am using a DNS server specific to our group. Sometimes I am able to access resources by the host name only, but sometimes I have to type the full name, domain included. For example, sometimes 'ssh host' works, but sometimes I need to use 'ssh host.team.domain'.

So far, I haven't seen any pattern as to when I need to enter the full name vs. when I can just use the host name. I am using them the same way each time, but some days it works and some days it doesn't.

Why might I be seeing something like this?

Comment: Do you have some DNS suffix defined in your Ethernet adapter settings ?

Comment: @user2196728 I did not, but defining one seems to have fixed the problem. I guess now my only question is, why did it sometimes work before without that?

Comment: That is the question ! :) that's why i didn't write it as an answer but a comment...Is the DNS server defined on your Win7 pc is the main DNS server for domain team.domain, or does it act as a DNS redirector for this domain ?

Comment: Okay - I think that when I am connected to the network via a wireless connection (Using DHCP instead of a static IP), it is picking up the DNS suffix there. When I disable the wireless network, and have no suffix set manually, that is when I run into problems.

Comment: That is a really good reason ! you didn't mention this use case in your question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to resolve `host` without adding any DNS suffix to `host` you have to set up a DNS suffix in your Ethernet adapter settings. So that the system is able to add the suffix by itself and it is transparent for you.

If you don't have a DNS suffix in your Ethernet adapter settings, then you will have to enter the full FQDN to communicate with the target host : `host.team.domain`.

Note that DHCP servers push the DNS suffix.